# input string was not in correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, executescalar

i have a webforms app using asp/C# .net with SQL server 2008. 
i have a login form that will authenticate access to my webform website.
here is the code.

```
SqlConnection an = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=REZRTECH\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Temp;Integrated Security=True");
            an.Open();
            SqlCommand anc = new SqlCommand();
            anc.Connection = an;
            anc.CommandText = "Select * From Logins where User_name = @usr";
            anc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", TextBox1.Text);



            int count = Convert.ToInt32(anc.ExecuteScalar());//throws input string was not in correct format exception.
            if (count == 0)
                {
                    string swa = "User Does Not Exist";
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + swa + "');", true);
                    return;                      
                }
                else
                {
                 //
                    //if user name and password match goto homepage
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string swa1 = "Invalid Login Credentials";
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + swa1 + "');", true);
                    }
```

my table rows are both nvarchar.
there is one other thing that is puzzling me, one user_name is admin and its corresponding password is also admin. suppose i enter any thing other than admin, it successfully gives me the error that user is not present. that time the "*input string exception is not thrown"*

any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your `anc.ExecuteScalar()` returns exactly? What do you achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Suspect that you want to get the total `Count` of users with the given `UserName`.
if you want to get the `Count` you need to follow the follwoing `SELECT` command Syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from [TableName] WHERE CNDITION;
```

SO you are missing Count(*) in your SELECT Statetement.

Replace This:

```
anc.CommandText = "Select * From Logins where User_name = @usr";
```

With This:

```
anc.CommandText = "Select count(*) From Logins where User_name = @usr";
```

Comment: It's a Rookie mistake i made by not using Count(*)...
Your tip works smoothly and without doing many other changes to my code... Thanks a lot bro..

Answer (score 2):

The exception is happening because you are using `ExecuteScalar`--designed to return only a single value--and expecting that value to be an `Int32` when it isn't. It seems your goal is to determine if the user is valid.

```
anc.CommandText = "select cast(count(1) as bit) from Logins where User_name = @usr";
```

then later, change `int count = ...` to `bool isUserValid = (bool)anc.ExecuteScalar()`.

Using `bool` instead of `int count` is a bit more descriptive and maintainable. There's no use in retrieving the count if you don't intend to use the count for something.

Comment: It's a Rookie mistake i made by not using Count(*)...
Even if i do it normal way it's doing what i need.
tried with your method too, working O.K, a good solution.